# Erro ao associar variável de conexão (PHP/MySQLi)

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estou encontrando dificuldade ao chamar uma variável de um código php auxiliar, que realiza a conexão com meu banco de dados, na minha página HTML.
Pesquisei em diversos conteúdos, porém não encontrei solução para este problema, aparentemente besta.

Minha conexão está sendo realizada com sucesso, já realizei testes. (conexao.php) :

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="database";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) 
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
  ?>
```

Porém quando incluo no arquivo principal (include), ao chamar a variável $con , a página HTML não retorna de forma correta:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');
$query = "select `id`, `nome`, `sexo` from `pessoas`"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset = "utf8">
    <head>
        <title> Empresa </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1> Empresa </h1>
    </header>
    <?php

    if($stmt = $con -> prepare($query)) {
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($id, $nome, $sexo); 
    ?>

        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>Sexo</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($stmt -> fetch()) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php printf("%s", $id) ?></td>
                    <td><?php printf("%s", $nome) ?></td>
                    <td><?php printf("%s", $sexo) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            } ?>
        </table>

        <?php
            $con -> close();
            } 
            else 
                echo "Erro ao executar a consulta no banco de dados."; 
        ?>
</body>
```

O erro persiste por todo código. Onde chamar a variável $con, exibe o código ao invés de executar determinado comando. Lembrando que salvo os arquivos dentro de uma pasta, e executo a partir do host conforme imagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Copiei seu código pro meu ambiente, editei os dados do db e tudo funcionou "como deveria"... Sem erros... Lógico que apareceu a msg "Connected successfullyConnected successfully", já que a conexão foi testada duas vezes...

Comment: @bfavaretto sim , eu entendo que não faz sentido, coloquei mais como um teste. E sobre a posição quanto à um header html, eu alteirei, mas não obtive sucesso.  Estarei expondo o código completo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Estou encontrando dificuldade ao chamar uma variável de um código php auxiliar, que realiza a conexão com meu banco de dados, na minha página HTML

Basicamente copiei e colei seu código, e tudo funcionou.

Logo depois, dei uma pequena implementada no seu código (comentários nos arquivos). Veja:

**conexao.php**:

```
$host       = "--";
$user       = "--";
$password   = "--";
$dbname     = "--";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar-se ao banco de dados: " . $con->connect_error);
} // else desnecessário: se não avisar erro, tudo está funcionando...
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

/*
* CÓDIGO DESNECESSÁRIO, JÁ QUE A CONEXÃO É TESTADA DIRETO NO ARQUIVO "conexao.php"
*
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} else echo "Connected successfully"; */

// testando a conexão "novamente"
echo '<pre>';
print_r($con);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Saída**:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $
    [client_version] => 50012
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.6.35
    [server_version] => 50635
    [stat] => Uptime: 4457  Threads: 2  Questions: 60  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 74  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 3  Queries per second avg: 0.013
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 22
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```

**@edit:**

Com seu código completo, re-escrevi baseando-me no seu. Você vai perceber que fiz uma reorganização e, no final, tudo funcionou como devido. (Foi mais fácil do que depurar seu código *que não estava retornando erro, simplesmente interrompia a execução do script*).

Veja:

```
<?php
    include('conexao.php');
    $query = "select `id`, `nome`, `cpf` from `funcionarios`";  // CONFORME A TABELA QUE USEI PARA TESTE
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset = "utf8">
    <head>
        <title> Empresa </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> Empresa </h1>
        </header>
        <?php
        if($stmt = $con -> prepare($query)) {
            $stmt -> execute();
            $stmt -> bind_result($id, $nome, $cpf); ?>
            <table border = "1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Nome</td>
                    <td>CPF</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while($stmt -> fetch()) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php printf("%s", $id) ?></td>
                        <td><?php printf("%s", $nome) ?></td>
                        <td><?php printf("%s", $cpf) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                } ?>
            </table>
            <?php
            $con -> close();
        } else echo "Erro ao executar a consulta no banco de dados."; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Saída**:

[image: by LipESprY]

Fiz o mínimo possível de alterações, salvo a formatação.

Comment: Qual o local onde você está salvando os arquivos .php e .html ? Ambos na mesma pasta ? E você utiliza algum ambiente de desenvolvimento web para trabalhar estes arquivos ? Eu estou utilizando o wamp. No meu caso, salvo na pasta /www, conforme estudos realizados.

Comment: Então, tem algo errado no seu código sim. Mas achei melhor reescrever (pouco código) e testar. Os arquivos estão na raiz do documento. Lado-a-lado.

Comment: Não acredito que o problema esteja no código porque copiei o seu e modifiquei somente os dados. Eu só encontro problema quando divido a conexão (conexao.php) do arquivo principal (index.html). Caso abra tudo num empresa.php, funciona normal.

Comment: Vc disse index.html? Não vai rodar mesmo! A extensão deve ser .php! Senão o código vai ser interpretado como HTML puro... Haha

Comment: Sabia que não se tratava de algo muito complexo !! Agora, em que momento eu utilizaria um index.html ?

Comment: html não é interpretado pelo php! Então tudo que estiver entre as tags do php (<?php ?>) será tratado como texto comum.

Comment: Isso não é uma verdade universal: "Vc disse index.html? Não vai rodar mesmo! A extensão deve ser .php" - depende só de como foi configurado o servidor de páginas. Qualquer extensão pode ser interpretada pelo PHP, e sem extensão também. Aliás. muito util para evitar certas gambiarras com `.htaccess` - Num servidor bem configurado, se deixar arquivos sem extensão passarem pelo PHP pode fazer algo como um PHP na raiz com nome `blog` ser acessado assim: `www.site.com/blog/bem-vindo`  - será executado o arquivo `blog`, e o /bem-vindo será uma variável do $_SERVER, permitindo rotas em PHP puro

Comment: @bacco Claro. Mas eu não queria implantar uma dúvida, que não se refere diretamente à pergunta, na cabeça do amigo perguntante. Basta observar o problema e já fica claro q ele é iniciante. O uso de outras extensões é tão baixo q, acredito eu, não mereça uma grande explicação. Fica aí uma dica para próxima pergunta! Hehe

Comment: @LipESprY sim, acho válido seu comentário no contexto. Sò quis deixar claro que nao é "obrigatório" pra abrir a cabeça de futuros leitores tambem (ou do autor da pergunta quando ele avançar).

Answer (score -3):

eu faço diferente tenta desta forma:

```
  $db = "nomdedodb";
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "usuario";
  $password = "senha";
  $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  $sql="sua query aqui por ex show tables";
  $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($result);
     echo "</pre>";
  }
```

Comment: O problema em que estou encontrando não é na conexão do banco de dados em sí, e sim no momento em que chamo variáveis de outro código php.

Answer (score -4):

Quando ocorreu comigo, o problema foi eu ter esquecido um "<?php" e ter colocado apenas "<?", daí o código quebrava na primeira chamada de instância ->